# Why is 'gvfs-mount' not working after a force stop

Tags: networking, mount, ftp, gvfs, smb

'gvfs-mount' doesn't work after using a ctrl+z once and reusing 'gvfs-mount' back again.
 Consider the situation ::

```
gvfs-mount smb://172.17.88.47
Password required for 172.17.88.47
User [nanda]: ^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 gvfs-mount smb://172.17.88.47
gvfs-mount smb://172.17.88.47
```

Then it doesn't work, It blinks, blinks and blinks but doesn't work.
Why is this happenning ?
But the command works after I quit terminal and start it again, then if I force stop it again It doesn't work untill I restart terminal again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> stops a process, does not terminate it. Than means that if a process has any file "locked" or any resource reserved in a kind-of exclusive way, it will not release them for other process to use. When you terminate the process (*in a normal way(1)*) the system will clean up after it, and the resources will be available again.

To terminate a process you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. Sometime <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> will not work; you can try then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> or, if even this does not work and you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> (it happens), then you have to kill it:

```
kill %1
```

(the number 1 is the number in brackets you see before the "stopped" message).

You can even continue the process (with `fg %1`) or send it to background (with `bg %1`). Search for "bash job control" for more information.

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) this is why it's better to use `kill -9` as a *last resort only*, after trying a plain `kill`.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect but could you please elaborate, I mean whats the practical difference between 'stops a process and terminates a process'

Comment: I added the requested info to the answer.